# C: Why does strcpy return its argument?

Tags: c, libc

Why does `strcpy(3)` (and `strncpy(3)`) return their first argument? I don't see how this does add any value. Instead, frequently I'd rather have the number of copied bytes returned.

Addendum: What am I supposed to do when I need also the length of the resulting string? Do I really have to implement my own version?

Comment: So that it can be used in function chaining.

Comment: It would be far more useful if a variant of `strcpy()` returned a pointer to the `'\0'` byte at the end of the string.  However, if you length check everything before you do your copying (as you should to be safe), you can use `memmove()` (or maybe `memcpy()`) instead of `strcpy()`.  It's only when you don't have a length available that can't use those, but it is arguably not safe to do the copying if you don't know the lengths of the source string and the target buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler re: _"It would be far more useful if a variant of strcpy() returned a pointer to the '\0' byte at the end of the string"_: There is (in POSIX).  It's called [`stpcpy(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stpcpy.3.html).

Comment: And, for chaining memcpy(3), there's GNU's `mempcpy(3)`.; the same with better return value

Answer (score 4):

For historical reasons. `strcpy` and friends date back to the early seventies, and I guess the intended use case for the return value would be a kind of chaining:

```
// copy src into buf1 and buf2 in a single expression
strcpy(buf1, strcpy(buf2, src));
```

Or

```
char *temp = xmalloc(strlen(const_str) + 1);
function_that_takes_mutable_str(strcpy(temp, const_str));
```

Comment: Didn't they have comma expressions at the time? `function1((strcpy(buf1, const_str), buf1))`.

Comment: @JoSo: I'm not sure when comma expressions were introduced, but I've read quite a lot of old C code and I don't think I ever saw it being used. I personally also never use it except in macros.

Answer (score 1):

So that you can do something like

```
char * str = strcpy(malloc(12), "MyNewString");
```

Comment: … the danger of which will not have escaped anyone who saw the version of this answer with `11` where `12` now is.

Comment: Why not just use strdup? Or was it missing at those times?

Comment: `strdup` is, I think, a 1980s addition, when C had already diverged into dialects. It wasn't in V7 Unix, it's still not in ISO C, even though POSIX has always had it.

Comment: The other danger with chaining with `malloc()` is the crash that occurs when the memory allocation fails!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you can do it with a custom `xmalloc`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the string functions in the C library have been designed by amateurs.  For instance, in my 25 years of my career, I never used the strcat() function, yet I concatenate strings all the time.  Also, if you think the printf(), there is little documentation if you pass NULL for a %s argument.  The same goes for for the %c passing a '\0', or a malloc(0).

Sadly, the most useful strcpy() should return a pointer to the end of the destination buffer to chain copying.